# How to organize spell-checking in web-app?

Tags: mysql, sql, spell-checking

We create spell-checking web-service, so we send data by Ajax, and it must response us all possible variants. We used the algorithm provided by Peter Norvig, which creates variants of insertion, deletion, substitution.
So for example for word sar it creates many variants like: aar,bar,car and etc.
Then search from list of predefined words, which of created variants are in list. So we will find that bar, car are possible variants of correct words.
So now problem is storing predefined words. We decided to store them in database.
We request from MySQL database if it has provided variants in database. MySQL shows an error that it cannot response, it shows an error:

> "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

It doesn't shows this error for short words, because they has less variants.

How we can organize this database and queries?
May be we shall use serialized files instead of database?
What is best for web-applications?

Comment: The way your question reads, your problem is not related to spell-checking at all but a simple question of using MySQL from a web service. It seems that you have a issue with your database connection, and that's the thing you need help for. I suggest you remove everything related to spell-checking and paste a little code that shows how you talk to the database instead. Otherwise it will be impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: It's probably some kind of timeout error... and chiccodoro is right, probably nothing to do with spell-checking